Category translation in TYPO3 not working as expected
TYPO3 12, PHP 8.2. I am trying to get the categories of my posts for some icons. Since i found no way of getting the categories directly in fluid i thought i'd give typoscript a try. This works fine in the base language, however the translations are empty. I have translated

the category container page
all categories
my page and it's content of course, the content itself is in the right language in the frontend

This is how i envoke it in fluid:
{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.categories', data:'{recordUid: data.uid}')}

This is my typoscript CONTENT object:
    lib.categories = CONTENT
    lib.categories {
            table = sys_category
            select {
                # set correct id for sys folder
                pidInList = 652
                selectFields = title, uid
                join = sys_category_record_mm ON sys_category_record_mm.uid_local = sys_category.uid    
                where.data = field:recordUid
                where.intval = 1
                where.wrap = uid_foreign=|
                languageField = sys_language_uid
            }

            renderObj = COA
            renderObj {
                1 = TEXT
                1 {
                    value = <li class="refcat refcat-{field:uid}"><span>{field:title} </span></li>                   
                    insertData = 1
                }
            }
        }

i have even checkd the db, my content elements objects have the exact same categories and settings in both languages. Any ideas? Can this be done in Fluid or maybe even with a userFunc?
Thanks

Please specify what your posts are.
You should be able to get the categories from your Post-Model. If not there is something wrong.

Its a custom post type, i only utilize core fields however. so there is no additional config involved except for the showitem property of the TCA. What do you mean by "You should be able to get the categories from your Post-Model"? That my TS above should in theory be working?
